# Error while doing ssh to localhost via putty

Tags: cygwin, sshd

I have Cygwin sshd setup on my windows 7.

I am trying to connect to localhost via ssh using putty.
I tried to connect by using host value as both localhost and IP address And Port:22

Everytime I login, I get below message and then putty window disappears.

```
login as: kalbha
kalbha@localhost's password:
Last login: Mon Jun 15 14:34:08 2015 from 20.86.280.218
```

I do no see any other message displayed. I do not see any error either.

Then I tried to connect through one TIBCO application.This application is also running locally and it tries to execute one command via connecting to localhost through SSH.
And it got below log message.

```
Attempting PASSWORD authentication to kalbha@20.86.280.218:22
Authentication SUCCESSFUL and session connected
Cannot connect to remote host at 20.86.280.218 through SSH. java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
```

I believe this is the reason my putty window is getting disappeared.

Can you tell me why I am getting this java error?